# Magento Email Template Footer

Tags: magento2, css

I created 2 E-Mail templates in Magento2. A Header and a footer.

In the header i can normally add in Template style below my style.

But in the footer Template Style area, it is not reading my css.

Am i doing something wrong or do i need to add a script tag or something else ?

Greets

Answer (score 0):

You need to change css for email template for header and footer. so must be override **vendor\magento\theme-frontend-blank\web\css\source_email-base.less**
and **_email-extend.less** and **_email-variables.less**

Change email template css as per your requirement.

> Note: after add new file you need to exec:theme name and then run
>   grunt watch command.

Answer (score 0):

You can go through [Magento docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-email.html), Here you can get explanations regarding the tags.

I hope it will help you.